# PHP Login with Facebook creating infinite redirect loop

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I am having an issue with Facebook Login and PHP.

The file below seems to be causing the issue.
Everything works until the point I login with Facebook successfully and the browser eventually throws out an infinite redirect error when redirecting back to this file. The last else statement is always being executed causing the loop...

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php


require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }


    if (!empty($user_profile )) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)

        $username = $user_profile['name'];
    $uid = $user_profile['id'];
    $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);

        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try commenting out `header("Location: home.php");` and `header("Location: " . $login_url);`, then see if you are still stuck...

Comment: What happens when you put `session_start();` at the top of the page? Per [Login for Server-side Apps](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) the session is required. And then you get a `$_GET['code']` for the status from the request.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in base_facebook.php

look for:

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2'
  );
```

and add the following 2 lines

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
```

so you have

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
     CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
);
```